# Printing sizeof(T) at compile time

Tags: c++, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to print out the size of a C++ class at compile-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008398/is-it-possible-to-print-out-the-size-of-a-c-class-at-compile-time)

Can I output the size of an object at compile time? Since the compiler already has this information when it is compiling a source file, can I ***see*** it (at compile time) rather than going through the lengthy process of outputting the size somewhere in my application's console or the debug output window?

This will be very useful especially when I am able to compile single source files which saves me tremendous amounts of time when working on large projects.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008398/is-it-possible-to-print-out-the-size-of-a-c-class-at-compile-time

Comment: Many compilers have a `#pragma` or other directive that can be used to output values during compilation. You'll have to check your compiler's documentation. Unfortunately I don't know how to get the compiler to evaluate the expression before it generates the output.

Comment: I'm not answering, because I'm no entirely sure, but I think the answer is no.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker, why do you think this is a different question? It looks exactly the same to me.

Comment: @MarkRansom, there were two links, I believe and, probably, I was referring to the other wan, that was about determining the size, not displaying it. Unless I went crazy since my last comment.

Comment: Definitely a duplicate, but the question's search terms did not match at all.

Comment: Samaursa, don't feel bad about not finding it through search and don't take the closing personally. It's a good thing to have different questions with different search terms, but it's also good to have all the answers in one place.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes. The possible duplicate prints the size as **error** message, which means the compilation will not succeed.

However, my solution prints the size as **warning** message, which means, it will print the size, and the compilation will continue.

```
template<int N> 
struct print_size_as_warning
{ 
   char operator()() { return N + 256; } //deliberately causing overflow
};

int main() {
        print_size_as_warning<sizeof(int)>()();
        return 0;
}
```

Warning message:

```
prog.cpp: In member function ‘char print_size_as_warning<N>::operator()() [with int N = 4]’:
prog.cpp:8:   instantiated from here
prog.cpp:4: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion
```

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/m9eg3

**Note : the value of N in the warning message is the value of sizeof(int)**

---

The above code is improved one, and my first attempt was this:

```
template<int N> 
struct _{ operator char() { return N+ 256; } }; //always overflow

int main() {
        char(_<sizeof(int)>());
        return 0;
}
```

Warning message:

```
prog.cpp: In member function ‘_<N>::operator char() [with int N = 4]’:
prog.cpp:5:   instantiated from here
prog.cpp:2: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion
```

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/mhXjU

The idea is taken from my previous answer to this question:

- [Calculating and printing factorial at compile time in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977715/calculating-and-printing-factorial-at-compile-time-in-c)